# Master Card Payment Gateway Services (MPGS) Issue With Hosted Checkout Interaction Page (Checkout.js)

Tags: javascript, payment-gateway, mastercard

I am new to Master Card Payment Gateway Services (MPGS) integration and facing issue with the second step to interact with master card secure payment page.

Step1: I have generated a session ID using the apiOperation as "CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION" using Postman with a POST method. The body was raw => Json as shown below:

```
URL: https://test-gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/57/merchant/1033/session

Body:
 { 
  "apiOperation": "CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION", 
  "interaction": {
      "operation": "PURCHASE"
  },
  "order": {
      "currency": "USD",
       "id": "22541" ,
      "amount": 50
    } 
}
```

And by giving my API credentials in the Authorization section generated the session ID successfully. Now when I call the checkout.js file to interact with the hosted checkout payment page, the control moves to the payment gateway page but showing an error

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://test-gateway.mastercard.com/form/version//merchant/1033/session.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5A76.png)

```js
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://test-gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/57/checkout.js" data-error="errorCallback" data-cancel="cancelCallback" data-complete="completeCallback"  >
            </script>
            
        <script type="application/javascript">
            function errorCallback(error) {
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
            function cancelCallback() {
                  console.log('Payment cancelled');
            }
            function completeCallback(resultIndicator, sessionVersion) {
    
            alert('success');
    console.log(resultIndicator);
}
            
            Checkout.configure({
                merchant: '1033',
                order: {
                    amount: function() {
                        return 50;
                    },
                    currency: 'USD',
                    description: 'Ordered goods',
                    id: '22541'
                },
                interaction: {
                    operation: 'PURCHASE',
                    merchant: {
                        name: 'MOFA -TEST',
                        address: {
                            line1: '200 Sample St',
                            line2: '1234 Example Town'     
                        }    
                    }
                },
                session: {
                      id: 'SESSION0002089703583J7873949J89'
                }
                
            });
            
            Checkout.showPaymentPage();
            
        </script>
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi, why are you using https://test-gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/57/checkout.js when in docs its different?

Answer (score 0):

The Mastercard payment gateway documentation is not clear in describing the parameter of the request. I found this video helpful for Mastercard hosted checkout integration using PHP curl and JavaScript:

Here's the code snippet to request for sessionId:

```
        $id = sanitize_text_field( $req['id'] );
    $amount  = sanitize_text_field( $req['amount'] );
    $merchantId = sanitize_text_field( $req['merchantId'] );
    $password = sanitize_text_field( $req['password'] );
    $redirectUrl = sanitize_text_field( $req['redirectUrl'] );

    $post_data = '{ 
        "apiOperation": "CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION", 
        "interaction": {
            "operation": "PURCHASE",
            "returnUrl": "' . $redirectUrl .'",
            "cancelUrl": "' . $redirectUrl . '",
        },
        "order": {
            "currency": "USD",
             "id": "' . $id . '",
            "amount": "' . $amount . '"
          } 
      }';

    $url = "https://fbn.gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/61/merchant/" . $merchantId . "/session";
    
    $auth = 'merchant.'. $merchantId . ':' . $password;
    $credentials = base64_encode($auth);
    $authorization = 'Authorization: Basic ' . $credentials;

    // Prepare new cURL resource
    $crl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
     
    // Set HTTP Header for POST request 
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Basic ' . $credentials)
    );
     
    // Submit the POST request
    $result = curl_exec($crl);
     
    // handle curl error
    if ($result === false) {
        // throw new Exception('Curl error: ' . curl_error($crl));
        //print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($crl));
        $result_noti = 0; die();
    } else {
        return rest_ensure_response( $result );
    }
    // Close cURL session handle
    curl_close($crl);
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRJkfszfla0

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30582364)

Answer (score 0):

MPGS Hosted Checkout Integration is updated from API version 63 and above. However if you are still using API version 57(minimum 3DS2.0 supported API version) find the sample code below. MPGS checkout.js HTML references [MPGS sample code version wise reference](https://eu-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/checkout/index.html?locale=en_US)

Checkpoints

- API version in HTML page is same as CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION API (No need to provide version number in HTML page for version >= 63)
- Session ID is correct
- Order ID is unique for each transaction

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://test-gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/57/checkout.js"
                data-error="errorCallback"
                data-cancel="cancelCallback">
        </script>
    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function errorCallback(error) {
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
            function cancelCallback() {
                  console.log('Payment cancelled');
            }
        
            Checkout.configure({
                session: {
                    id:  'SESSION0002892865938N27989233E3'
                 },
                order: {
                    description: 'Ordered goods',
                    id: 'bqtrb-xryt'
                },
                interaction: {
                    merchant: {
                        name: 'Merchant name',
                        address: {
                            line1: '200 Sample St',
                            line2: '1234 Example Town'
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div id="embed-target"> </div>
        <input type="button" value="Pay with Lightbox" onclick="Checkout.showLightbox();" />
        <input type="button" value="Pay with Payment Page" onclick="Checkout.showPaymentPage();" />
    
    </body>
</html>
```